# How do i access a function from another file in python with Tkinter. I can't find any solution to my specific problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python and Tkinter so I might be making a simple mistake here, but it's for a school project, therefore, I do not have much time to learn everything. Anyways I am making an app with Tkinter and I wanted to split up the code into different python files, functions in one file and accessing them from the main. I have been trying to figure out what's wrong for 3days now and it looks like a very simple mistake but I don't know what it is.

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\mcdd1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1884, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "d:\mcdd1\Desktop\UNI\Switch-Frames-Template-master\textfunc.py", line 22, in open_file
> my_text.delete("1.0", END)
> NameError: name 'my_text' is not defined

these are the codes that I've used:
the main file is mainnav.py,

```
from textfunc import open_file

toolbar_frame = Frame(frame2, bg="blue")
toolbar_frame.pack(fill=X)

my_frame = Frame(frame2)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

my_text = Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 16), selectbackground="yellow", selectforeground="black", undo=True, wrap="none")
my_text.pack()

open_button = Button(toolbar_frame, text="Open", command=open_file)
open_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
```

the file with the functions textfunc.py (in the same directory)

```
global open_status_name
open_status_name = False
global selected
selected = False

def open_file():
    
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)

    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="", title="Open File", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    
    if text_file:
        global open_status_name
        open_status_name = text_file
    
    text_file = open(text_file, 'r')
    stuff = text_file.read()
    my_text.insert(END, stuff)
    text_file.close()
```

these are just the snippets of code I think would be needed to troubleshoot the problem. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **my_text** variable is not defined in your **mainnav.py** file. You can pass it as an argument to the **open_file()** function if you want to access it:

mainnav.py:

```
from textfunc import open_file

toolbar_frame = Frame(frame2, bg="blue")
toolbar_frame.pack(fill=X)

my_frame = Frame(frame2)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

my_text = Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 16), selectbackground="yellow", selectforeground="black", undo=True, wrap="none")
my_text.pack()

open_button = Button(toolbar_frame, text="Open", command=lambda: open_file(my_text))
open_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
```

textfunc.py:

```
def open_file(my_text):
    
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)

    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="", title="Open File", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    
    if text_file:
        global open_status_name
        open_status_name = text_file
    
    text_file = open(text_file, 'r')
    stuff = text_file.read()
    my_text.insert(END, stuff)
    text_file.close()
```

Note: you need to use lambda for passing argument to the Button's command.